# How can I attach two objects so they can act like one while posing/animating in Blender

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, 3d-manipulator

[image: How it looks]

I want the Head object to be attached to the Body object as if they were one object. This is necessary so that I can change the head without changing the body (for example, in Unreal Engine).

Comment: If each vertex has the same weight as the overlapping one, it should work, please share your file so that we can test?